# Cocoapods "OTHER_LDFLAGS " Duplicate symbols because of -all_load

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, linker-errors

My app uses a vendor - static library that doesn't like the "-all_load" linker flag. It would throw duplicate errors if i used it.

The problem i have right now is i need to use the new box sdk as well. The [podspec](https://github.com/box/box-ios-sdk/blob/master/box-ios-sdk.podspec) of the SDK has the below.

```
s.xcconfig = { "OTHER_LDFLAGS" => "-ObjC -all_load" }
```

Therefore, the build fails with duplicate symbols in the vendor lib.

I've read online that i can avoid getting in such a situation by using `-force_load` only on the library that needs `-ObjC -all_load`. I cannot use that as a solution because i have no control over [BOX podspec](https://github.com/box/box-ios-sdk/blob/master/box-ios-sdk.podspec)

Is there a way i can override any of these in my app; I'd really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After battling with this for a few hours, i figured how to get this done. Posting it here so that it might help someone who get into a similar problem. I added the below post_install hook to the Podfile and voi-la it worked!!

```
post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            if target.name == "Pods"
                xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
                xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
                new_xcconfig = xcconfig.gsub("-ObjC -all_load",'-force_load $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libPods-box-ios-sdk.a')
                File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << new_xcconfig }
            end
        end
    end
end
```